# Definition of left regular representation of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't really understand the definition of left regular representation of $G$. Could anyone give me some explanation or examples?

> The permutation representation afforded by left multiplication on the elements of $G$ (cosets of $H = 1$) is called the left regular representation of $G$.

Comment: Did you try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation ?

Comment: In the wiki article, they still use the term "afford". What does it mean?

Comment: Hmm, means that $L(x)$ sends $g$ to $xg$ (multiplication from the left). I don't know why they use "afford" (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/afford).

Comment: Hmm~ Now I get it, thank you! @DietrichBurde

Comment: if you can see my answer for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496096/use-every-non-abelian-group-of-order-6-has-a-non-normal-subgroup-of-order-2-to-c it would be more clear i guess... left regular representation is a homomorphism of $G$ to $S_{|G|}$ considering multiplication of fixed element of $G$ by each element of $G$ giving an element in $S_{|G|}$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group, then you can get an homomorphisms 
$$ f \colon G \to S(G)$$
where $S(G)$ is the group of permutations on $G$, defined as the mapping that send every $g \in G$ in the mapping $f(g) \colon G \to G$ such that for every $x \in G$ the equation 
$$f(g)(x)=gx$$
holds.

Associativity and unit axioms grant that $f$ is an homomorphism of groups:

- for all $g,h \in G$ and $x \in G$ we have 
  $$f(gh)(x)=(gh)x=g(hx)=f(g)(hx)=f(g)(f(h)(x))=f(g)\circ f(h)(x)$$
- for all $x \in G$ the equality
  $$f(1)(x)=1x=x$$
  holds.

This homomorphism $f$ is the left regular representation (it represents the elements of the group $G$ as symmetries of the same group seen just as a set).

The name left is to distinguish from the (anti)-homomorphism 
$$f' \colon G \to S(G)$$
that to every $g \in G$ associate $f'(g) \colon G \to G$ such that for every $x \in G$ we have $f'(g)(x) = xg$.

Via the correspondence between actions and homomorphisms in symmetric groups left regular representation are those representation that correspond to left-action of $G$ on itself given by multiplication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Giorgio. Just to confirm: So if we have $G = \{1,2,3\}$, then $\pi(G) = S_3$. For example, $S = (1 \ 2 \ 3) \in \pi(G)$ takes $1 \in G$ to 2 - right...?

Comment: @Tumbleweed Well it seems true, but I don't get the relevance of this for the question.