# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of prime index $p$, $\exists g\in G$ such that $G/H=\{H,gH,\ldots,g^{p-1}H\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup of prime index $p$. I am trying to show that there exists an element $g\in G$ such that
$$G/H=\{H,gH,g^2H,\ldots,g^{p-1}H\}$$
**My attempt:** By considering the (transitive) action of $G$ on $G/H$, we have a homomorphism
$$\psi:G\longrightarrow S_p$$
and thus $\psi(G)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$. It follows that $p$ divides $\psi(G)$ and thus, by Cauchy's theorem, there is an element $\psi(g)\in\psi(G)$ of order $p$. Then, $\psi(g^p)=\psi(g)^p=1$, so $g^p \in\ker\psi\subseteq H$, whence $g^pH=H$. The result would then follow if we can show that $g^k\notin H$ for $1\leq k\leq p-1$, but I didn't find a way to show that.

Comment: Look at [Normal subgroup of prime index](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/164244/8271)

Comment: @leo Here $p$ is not necessarily the smallest prime dividing $|G|$. How is that question useful for my question?

Comment: If $p$ were the minimal prime dividing $|G|$, then the linked post shows that the quotient $G/H$ is in fact a cyclic group, therefore such a $g$ must exist.

Comment: I thought you missed that assumption. Thanks for clarify that.

Comment: @leo Yes thanks. The question is indeed more general than that. $G/H$ might be just a set, not a group.

Comment: Why $\psi(G)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$? and why $p$ divides $\psi(G)$?

Comment: @eraldcoil Apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: @caffeinemachine thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the element $\psi(g)$ of order $p$, let us first verify that $g \notin H$. Suppose you had $g\in H$. Then $\psi(g^k)$ would fix $H$ for all $k$, so $\psi(g)$ would be a permutation of the $p-1$ other cosets of $H$, of order $p$. But $p \nmid (p-1)!$, so that can't be.

Hence we have $\psi(g)H \neq H$. Now consider the order of the orbit of $H$ under $\psi(g)^k$. Let that order be $n$. We saw $n > 1$. But $\psi(g)^p = \operatorname{id}$, hence $n \mid p$, so $n = p$, since $p$ is prime.