# $ H $ is a subgroup of $G$ of prime index $p$ , $\exists g\in G$ such that $G/H=\left\{H,gH,…,g^{p-1}H\right\}$ .

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and let $[G:H]=n$. We consider here the question of whether there is an element in $g\in G$ such that $\left\{H,gH,\ldots,g^{n-1}H\right\}$ are all the cosets of $H$ in $G$.

(a) Show that if $n$ is not a prime this may fail.

(b) Show that if $n$ is prime such $g$ always exists. (Suggestion: Show first that a transtive subgroup of $S_n$ has order divisible by $n$. Show then that a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ has an element of order $p$. Use the coset representation to finish the proof. You may use Cauchy'theorem : a finite subgroup whose order is divisible by a prime $p$ has an element of order $p$.)

In (a), I can't find a simple counterexample.

In (b) by [If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of prime index $p$, $\exists g\in G$ such that $G/H=\{H,gH,\ldots,g^{p-1}H\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533680/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-g-of-prime-index-p-exists-g-in-g-such-that-g-h)

the solution is:

By considering the (transitive) action of $G$ on $G/H$, we have a homomorphism
$$\psi:G\longrightarrow S_p$$
and thus $\psi(G)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$. It follows that $p$ divides $\psi(G)$ and thus, by Cauchy's theorem, there is an element $\psi(g)\in\psi(G)$ of order $p$.

With the element $\psi(g)$ of order $p$, let us first verify that $g \notin H$. Suppose you had $g\in H$. Then $\psi(g^k)$ would fix $H$ for all $k$, so $\psi(g)$ would be a permutation of the $p-1$ other cosets of $H$, of order $p$. But $p \nmid (p-1)!$, so that can't be.

Hence we have $\psi(g)H \neq H$. Now consider the order of the orbit of $H$ under $\psi(g)^k$. Let that order be $n$. We saw $n > 1$. But $\psi(g)^p = \operatorname{id}$, hence $n \mid p$, so $n = p$, since $p$ is prime.

I don't see that:

(i) so $\psi(g)$ would be a permutation of the $p-1$ other cosets of $H$, of order $p$. But $p \nmid (p-1)!$, so that can't be.

My doubt:
 $\psi(g)$ would be a permutation of the $p-1$ other cosets of $H$, of order $p$. Then  $p \mid (p-1)!$?

Comment: For a counterexample when $n$ is not prime, let $G$ be the quaternion group $Q_8$ and $H = \{1, -1\}$.

Comment: Regarding your question about (i): could you be more specific about what you don't understand? If we go through the proof presented, then what is the **first** point at which something becomes unclear?

Comment: Example for a: consider $G = \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$, and take $H = \{(0,0,0),(1,0,0)\}$. Here, $\Bbb Z_2 = \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, which is to say that it is the cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: A permutation of $p-1$ elements can be identified with an element of $S_{p-1}$, which has order $(p-1)!$. Therefore such a permutation cannot have order $p$, since $p$ is prime and therefore does not divide $(p-1)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for part (a): Look for a counterexample with $H = \{1\}$.

For (b), if $\psi(g)$ fixes some element $k \in \{1, \dot, p\}$, then it belongs to the subgroup $K$ of $S_p$ consisting of those permutations fixing $k$. But $|K| = (p-1)!$. Since $p$ doesn't divide $(p-1)!$, this contradicts the fact that $\psi(g)$ has order $p$.

Incidentally, there's what I would consider an easier way to finish (b) by noting that any element of $S_p$ of order $p$ must be a $p$-cycle. Knowing that $\psi(g)$ acts as a $p$-cycle on the conjugates of $H$ tells you what you want to prove.

Comment: I have that $G:=Z_2\times Z_2 and H=\left\{(0,0)\right\}$ works.
$G/H=\left\{H,(1,0)+H,(0,1)+H,(1,1)+H\right\}$ and $(1,0)+(1,0)=(0,0), (0,1)+(0,1)=(0,0), (1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)$

Comment: Your choice of $G$ and $H$ will work, but I don't understand what point you're making by saying $(1,1) = (1,0) + (0,1)$. If $H = \{1\}$, any non-cyclic $G$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

For $a)$, consider $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/(2\Bbb Z\times2\Bbb Z)$.