# example of a subgroup of index $3$ which is not normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

Could you please give an example of a subgroup of index $3$ which is not normal ?

I know every subgroup of index $2$ is normal but if index is $3$ , I have no idea whether all of the subgroups are normal or not.

Comment: Consider subgroups of $S_3$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** Consider $S_3$ and the subgroup $\langle(1\ 2)\rangle$.

Comment: thank you but can you be more specefic

Comment: $H = \langle (1 \ 2) \rangle = \{1, (1 \ 2)\}$, that is, the subgroup generated by the transposition $(1 \ 2)$. Since the symmetric group $S_3$ contains $3! = 6$ elements and $|H| = 2$, you have that the index of $H$ is 3. Do you know how to show that a subgroup is normal?

Answer (score 2):

As Ian Coley point out $S_3$ is smallest counter  example of it.

But it is true if $G$ has odd order.

**Fact**: Let $p$ be smallest prime dividing $|G|$ then any group of index $p$ is normal.

Notice that when $|G|$ is odd and $3$ divides $|G|$, then $3$ is the smallest prime dividing $G$.

For fact you can check this.

[Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index)

Comment: Thank you that was usefull

Comment: @SaeidGhafouri : you are welcome.