# $H,K \lt G$ with $HK=G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a group and $H \lt G$ and $K \lt G$, with $|G|=n$ then If $GCD( (G:H) ,(G:K))=1$ then $G=HK$

Any thoughts?

**Edit by Batominovski:** To prevent this thread from being closed or getting unnecessary downvotes, the OP has made an attempt to solve the problem.  But the attempt was wrong, so it was removed.

Comment: What is MDC?  Is it GCD?

Comment: @Batominovski yup, forgot tô translate, Will do

Comment: You write LCD, but do you mean GCD? I mean if lcm$(k,l)=1$, then $k=1=l$.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the intersection of $H$ and $K$ is trivial.  For example, take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5$, $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times 0$, and $K=0\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: @NickyHekster fixed it

Comment: @Batominovski actually i was looking to the wrong place, will delete this part

Comment: I First read as G and K with GCD = 1 not the quocients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that $G$ is a finite group (due to the tag "finite-groups" and the quote "$|G|=n$").  Note  (for example, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180888/size-of-the-product-of-two-subgroups)) that
$$|HK|\,|H\cap K|=|H|\,|K|\,.$$
That is, 
$$\frac{|HK|}{|H|}=\frac{|K|}{|H\cap K|}=[K:H\cap K]\in\mathbb{Z}\,.$$
Similarly, 
$$\frac{|HK|}{|K|}=\frac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}=[H:H\cap K]\in\mathbb{Z}\,.$$
That is, $|H|$ and $|K|$ both divides $|HK|$.  This mean $\text{lcm}\big(|H|,|K|\big)$ divides $|HK|$, or
$$|HK|\geq \text{lcm}\big(|H|,|K|\big)\,.$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}\leq \frac{|G|}{\text{lcm}\big(|H|,|K|\big)}=\gcd\left(\frac{|G|}{|H|},\frac{|G|}{|K|}\right)\,.$$
From the given condition 
$$\gcd\left(\frac{|G|}{|H|},\frac{|G|}{|K|}\right)=\gcd\big([G:H],[G:K]\big)=1\,,$$
we conclude that
$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}\leq 1\text{ or }|G|\leq |HK|\,.$$
Since $HK\subseteq G$ and $G$ is a finite set, we deduce that $G=HK$.

---

**P.S.**  We indeed have the following proposition.  See a comment by xsnl below for a sketch of a proof.

> **Proposition.**  Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of an arbitrary (finite or infinite) group $G$ such that $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are finite.  Suppose further that $\gcd\big([G:H],[G:K]\big)=1$.  Then, $G=HK$.

Comment: It follows from finite case. $[G, H \cap K] \leq [G, H][G, K]$, in particular, is finite. $H \cap K$ can be not normal, but taking intersection of conjugates we have finite quotient of $G$ with kernel contained in both $H$ and $K$. Images of $H$ and $K$ generate it, so $G = HK$.

Comment: @xsnl Great argument!  If you put that as an answer here, I will upvote it.  This deserves to be an answer.