# $H$ is a subgroup of $G $ with smallest possible prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of  $G $ with smallest possible prime index. Then $H$ is normal in $G$.

Above exercise is one of the classical exercises in group theory. The classical solution depends on group action on cosets of $H$. I want to share a proof not depending on group action. If you have other solutions, please share.

**proof:** If $H$ is not normal then assume $H\neq H^g$. Then $$|HH^g|=|H|\dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap H^g|}$$.

Notice that $\dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap H^g|}\geq p$. Thus, $|HH^g|\geq G$. We must have $HH^g=G$.

$g=hg^{-1}kg$ for some $h,k\in H$. Then $g=kh\in H$. As a result $H=G$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: What is $H^g$?  Do you mean $gHg^{-1}$?

Comment: @D_S: Yes, $H^g=g^{-1}Hg$ and to be able to say that $\dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap H^g|}\geq p$, I used the fact that $p$ is minimal.

Comment: At the end of the above, you get that $\;g=kh\in H\;$ ...but this was so **only** for this particular $\;g\in G\;$ for which $\;H\neq H^g\;$ . What about $\;x\in H\;$ if, for example, $\;H=H^x\;$ ? Say, for $\;x\in N_G(H)\;$ ?

Comment: The first part is similar to the way I did in my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index/268484#268484 but you have found a nice way to avoid using that groups of order $p^2$ are abelian here.

Comment: @Joanpemo The point is that the assumption was that for some $g\in G$ we had $H\neq H^g$ and this is what leads to the contradiction.

Comment: Actually, the conclusion should be changed to $g\in H$ so $H = H^g$ which is the contradiction (you have indeed not shown that $H = G$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you, exactly my point: we cannot deduce $\;H=G\;$ from the *particular* case of that particular $\;g\in G\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo: when we see that $g\in H$, then $HH^g =HH=H=G$ which is also contradiction, I think ?

Comment: @mesel Again, no: you can **not** deduce $\;H=G\;$ because one **particular** $\;g\in G\;$ , namely: one for which $\;H\neq H^g\;$ is *also* in $\;H\;$ . Please read above and also Tobias' comments.

Comment: @Joanpemo: Sometimes your proof can reach contradiction. You may not notice. But beauty of math is that you reached another contradicton. Again  
 the above proof is not wrong.

Comment: @Mesel Perhaps I'm missing something, but all I can see you can reach is, *perhaps*, that $\;H=H^g\;$ , which of course would also be a contradiction.

Comment: @Joanpemo: By assuming $x$, you reached $y$ and by fact a, you can reach contradiction but you missed it. Then by $y$ you reached $z$ and by fact b you reached contradiction. I reach contradiction by the fact $H$ was a proper subgroup. (fact b) . You suggest that before that it contradict to fact that $H\neq H^g$. (fact a). Your suggestion is better yet what I mean is that above solution is not wrong from logical point of view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  I had thought that it was beneficial for the people in this comunity yet I see that it is not very interesting for them beside that it is not a question. That is why I want to vote my post to be closed.

Comment: @mesel rather than voting to close your own question, you could just delete it?

Comment: You could add this as an answer to the question I linked.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thanks, I added.