# Show that if a group $G$ has odd order, any subgroup $H$ of index 3 in $G$ is normal in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that if a group $G$ has odd order, any subgroup $H$ of index 3 in
>   $G$ is normal in $G$.

I think this is equivalent to the following: Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$, with $K \leq H$. We can then show that $[G:K]=[G:H] \cdot [H:K]$. However, I'm not sure what the best approach is here. What's a good way to prove this theorem?

This question is different from [Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index) because we are not assuming that $3$ divides the order of $G$.

Comment: The only way I can see that the two statements are equivalent is in the fact that they are both true. For the one you are asking about, there is a general result that a subgroup of index $p$ where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group will be normal (there are several ways to show that)

Comment: I edited the question to explain why this is not a duplicate of "Normal subgroup of prime index". Can someone please explain why they think otherwise?

Comment: While it might not be an exact duplicate, it is answered by any answer to the linked question

Comment: Regarding the question posed in the edit: $|G| = |H|[G:H]$, so $3$ must divide $|G|$.

Comment: @Bungo sorry but why does $|G|=|H|[G:H]$ imply that $3$ must divide $|G|$?

Comment: $[G:H] = 3$, no?

Comment: @Bungo ah yes, thank you.

Comment: I now see this is a duplicate of the linked question, so a moderator is welcome to close this question or whatever. Not sure exactly what the procedure is. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the order of a subgroup is odd and the index of the subgroup is $3$ this implies that $3$ divides the order of the group.since $3$ is the least prime dividing the order of the group.hence every subgroup of index $3$ is normal

Comment: Why the downvote