# Proof verification on Group theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

$PROBLEM$ :If $G$ is finite of odd order. And $H$ subgroup of $ G$ with $[G:H]=3$ then $H$ is normal.

$Proof$:

I know that that there exists a homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow S_3 $ Such that $ker(\phi)<H$.I know that cause of i found it in the notes calling it Poincare's Trick.But i havent found a proof.(Id love to see a proof). Now that granted.

I know $\phi(G)<S_3$  and since $\phi$ not an isomorphism since $|G|=odd$ and $|S_3|=even$. 
So   $|\phi(G)|\mid |S_3|$ so $|\phi(G)|=2$ or $3$.

Now i know $$G/ker\phi \simeq \phi(G) $$ meaning  $|G/ker\phi |= |\phi(G)| $
And that must be an $odd$ since it is the $index$   of $ker\phi $  in $G$. So $$|\phi(G)|=|G/ker\phi|=3$$

Now  i know $$|G|=[G:H]|H|$$ and $$|G|=[G:Ker\phi]|Ker\phi|$$ substituting with $3$. I get  $$|H|=|Ker\phi| $$ and since $Ker\phi < H$ $\Rightarrow$
$Ker\phi=H$ .And i know  $Ker\phi \lhd G$ So its $H$ too.

Am i wrong?Afraid of some sort of circular reasoning.Also id love to see a proof of why there is such homomorphism.

Im asking if my  proof is correct and it is not a duplicate of the same problem.Since Im not asking for a proof but for a proof verification and a proof of a Trick mentioned!!

Comment: But this is exactly like the proof of the link. Just continue reading there, and remember the comments, which you got already (and have deleted).

Comment: Compare also with the duplicates [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761663/show-that-if-a-group-g-has-odd-order-any-subgroup-h-of-index-3-in-g-is-no), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index). Arturo is doing this proof for you, like you have asked.

Comment: ok. I hope next time ill ask something youll be offline.Good day to you.And both of these "duplicates" do not aswer the part for which i ask about the existance of the such homomorphism.

Comment: Why not? What is missing? The homomorphism is left multiplication acting on the cosets.

Comment: nvm i found it !! thank you.

Comment: OK, this sounds better than your previous comment ...

Comment: i am indeed.The first time you marked it as a duplicate .It wasnt .So dont be hasty shutting down questions thats all.In this one you did it the right way.And covered the whole question.So thanks but be cautious.

Comment: All right, I will. And for you, also look at possible answers on this site before posting. It is no fun, if a question comes up a hundred times again, with some minor change in the proof verification.