# For G acting on $\Omega$, let $\alpha \in \Omega$, show that $\operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha) \vartriangleleft G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Let G be a finite group, acting on a set $\Omega$, and let p be the smallest prime number such that $p \biggr||G|$. Let $\alpha \in \Omega$. It's known that $|\operatorname{Orb}_G(\alpha)| = p$. Prove that $\operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha) \vartriangleleft G$.

What I've done so far: if p is the smallest prime dividing G's order. then the biggest subgroup of G (which isn't G) will be of maximum order of $\frac{|G|}{p}$. 
$\forall \beta \in \operatorname{Orb}_G(\alpha),\  \left|\operatorname{Stab}_G(\beta)\right| = \frac{|G|}{|\operatorname{Orb}_G(\beta)|} = \frac{|G|}{|\operatorname{Orb}_G(\alpha)|}=\frac{|G|}{p}$. 
For every $g \in G:\ g(\alpha) = \alpha $ we get that $\forall s \in \operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha),\ g^{-1}sg \in \operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha)$, and for $\forall g \in G:\ g(\alpha) \neq \alpha$ we get for $\beta := g^{-1}(\alpha) \in \operatorname{Orb}_G(\alpha)$ that $\forall s \in \operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha),\ g^{-1}sg \in \operatorname{Stab}_G(\beta)$.
This transformation from $\operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha)$ to $\operatorname{Stab}_G(\beta)$ is injective, and the two subgroups are of the same order, so every member of $\operatorname{Stab}_G(\beta)$, for any $\beta \in \operatorname{Orb}_G(\alpha)$ is of this form.

I'm not sure how to continue from here. I need to show that all the stabiliziers subgroups are equal, or take a completely different approach. I haven't used the fact that this are p (potentially) different subgroups of the maximal possible size, which I believe is somehow relevant.

Comment: Ignoring the group action stuff, this is a standard exercise. See [groupprops](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_index_equal_to_least_prime_divisor_of_group_order_is_normal) or [planetmath](http://planetmath.org/normalityofsubgroupsofprimeindex) or [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index).

Comment: For me the "group action" stuff makes this different enough.  We need to "translate" the information about the size of the orbit into the index of the stabilizer.