# Is S3 maximal subgroup in S4?

Tags: group-theory

Is S3 maximal subgroup in S4.  As, I know if a subgroup is maximal then it should be normal isn't it? then is S3 normal in S4?

Comment: No, maximal subgroups of $G$ do not have to be normal in $G$. Yes, $S_3$ is a maximal subgroup if $S_4$, but it is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: All of the copies of $S_3$ are conjugate.  Why do you think maximal subgroups are normal (they're not)?

Comment: @student A possible go to example when checking claims like, "maximal subgroups are normal", is to think that there are groups with no nontrivial normal subgroups, but every non-cyclic group has nontrivial maximal subgroup (by finite induction)

Comment: @PaxKivimae;Is there any type of group, where maximal subgroups are always normal? Or any property to be normal?

Comment: There are various conditions of when a subgroup is normal (other than the definition).  For example, if it is a unique subgroup of a certain order.  Another condition is if $[G:H]$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ (see [for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index) )

Comment: thank you, I am expecting some property for maximal to be Normal. Anyway, the attached answer was nice.

Comment: If $[G:H]$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ is a special case of being maximal...

Comment: @MichaelBurr:  yes, got it. Thank you