# A finite simple group with subgroup for every divisor of $|G|$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group.

Assume that for every positive integer $d$ that divides $|G$, there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|H| = d$.

Prove that $G$ is abelian.

So I'm really out of ideas here...

I don't know much theorems that is about both simple and abelian groups...

I was thinking about - since $G$ is simple, and $Z(G)$ is always a normal subgroup, $Z(G)$ can be either $G$, or $\{e\}$.

So we only need to prove that $Z(G)$ is not trivial, and we are done..

Any hints on how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$, and let $p$ be the least prime factor of
$n$. There is a theorem to the effect that if $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of
index $p$, then $H$ is normal in $G$. (Hint: consider the action of
$G$ on the left cosets of $H$). If $G$ is simple, then $H$ must be trivial,
and so $G$ has order $p$.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index. (These type of arguments are not obvious unless you've seen them before.)

Comment: And then, it is isomorphic to a cyclic group and therefore abelian?

Comment: @ChikChak Exactly!

Comment: Thank you, this is a really great solution. And yet, out of curiosity, could there be any way doing it as I started?(trying to prove that $|G|=Z(G)$)?