# Conjugation action on cosets

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H < G$, does conjugation given an action on cosets of $H$ via $g \cdot xH = gxHg^{-1}$?

If it does it seems there is an easier proof to the problem in [Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index), where we show that a subgroup of index the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ is normal, by showing that $G$ must embed into $S_p$ trivially and therefore $g \cdot H = gHg^{-1} = H$ for all $g$, which implies that $H \lhd G$.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is $gHg^{-1}$ a coset if it is not equal to $H$?

Comment: Well, I originally had it as $g \cdot xH = g(xH)g^{-1} = (gxg^{-1})H$ - is that not a coset? I think the same question remains when I define it that way.

Comment: Your last equality there is not correct.