# A finite non-abelian group of order $n$ that for every divisor of $n$ has a subgroup is not simple

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be non-abelian group of order $n$. Also, for every $k$ which is a divisor of $n$ , there is a subgroup of $G$ of order $k$.
I want to prove that $G$ is not simple.

Well, from what is given, I see that there is a subgroup of order $p$ for every prime $p$ that divides $n$. However, I don't see how it helps. I am not sure how to use the fact that $G$ is not abelian too.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The abelian case is trivial because in an abelian group , every subgroup is normal. Therefore the assumption that the group is not abelian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $n=|G|$. Then there is a subgroup of order $k=\frac{n}{p}$, which is a divisor of $n$. However, it is well-known that every such subgroup of index $p$ is normal:

[Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index)

Hence $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Yeah that is sufficient to prove it. Thanks