# About coset and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H\le G$ and suppose that $[G:H]$ is the least positive prime factor of $|G|$.

How to show that $H\triangleleft G$?

I am confused in how to establish relation between the number of cosets of $H$ and its normalization. What does the condition "least prime factor" restrict for?

Where should I begin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index)

Comment: Begin with the construction of a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_p$, whose kernel is contained in $K$, the subgroup of index $p$ (see the duplicate).