# In a group $G$, of order $p^k$ has a subgroup of order $p^{k-1}$ prove this subgroup is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, p-groups

I have looked at many proofs that show that there exists a normal
subgroup of size $p^{k-1}$, but no proofs that all subgroups of
size $p^{k-1}$ are normal.

Comment: Look up the general theorem that if $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of a finite group $G$, all subgroups of $G$ with index $p$ are normal. That explains what you are asking and why a subgroup of index $2$ is always normal.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty normal group theory problem.

Comment: Its index is the smallest prime that divides the order of the group. Then apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index/164255#164255)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Wild that you remember your answers from more than 8 years ago.

Comment: @DonThousand: That particular problem comes up a lot, so I know I've answered it. Then I searched for it.

Comment: @DonThousand nice use of "normal" in your comment.

Comment: @KCd I thought it was pretty punny :)