# A question on the proof "Normal subgroup of prime index"

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

A question on the proof ["Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index)"

On Arturo's Magidin answer, it states that

> Then $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$, and so has order dividing $p!$"

Why it that true? I thought in order to have an isomorphism between $2$ groups, they must have the same order, since it's a $1-1$ and onto function.

How do you prove this?

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$.

Comment: @lulu ohh I see its to A subgroup of $S_p$ not the group $S_p$

Comment: @lulu i just used the 1 isomorphism theorem and make the assuption it was the hole $S_p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Lagrange's Theorem. For any subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$, we have $$|H|\mid |G|.$$

A proof can be found in any textbook on group theory or, indeed, abstract algebra, worth its salt.

Comment: I have dyslexia, so I read "to the " subgroup etc, silly question, thanks for clarifying

Comment: You're welcome, @lupusnox. Some of the best insights come from supposedly "silly" questions, so don't worry.