# Questions regarding the existence of normal subgroup with finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

> If $G$ is a group with a subgroup $H$ of finite index $n$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ whose index in $G$ is finite.

I found a proof of the question here: [How to prove that if $G$ is a group with a subgroup $H$ of index $n$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup $K\subset H$ whose index in $G$ divides $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88719/how-to-prove-that-if-g-is-a-group-with-a-subgroup-h-of-index-n-then-g-h)

I have a few questions regarding this proof:

1. The map $\phi: G \to \text{Sym}(X)$ given by $\phi(x)(aH)=(xa)H$ takes an argument from $G$. Why do we have $(aH)$ behind $\phi(x)$? What does the notation mean? Can we write $\phi(x)=xG/H$ instead?

2.How do I show that $\phi: G \to \text{Sym}(X)$ given by $\phi(x)(aH)=(xa)H$ is a homomorphism? I don't see immediately that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means that $\phi(x)$ is a function, and it takes as input $aH$ and returns as output $xaH$.
2. $\phi(xy)$ takes $aH$ and gives $xyaH$. $\phi(x) \phi(y)$ takes $aH$ and first gives $yaH$, then $xyaH$.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask one more question? Does it mean that $\ker(\phi(x)):=\lbrace x \mid (xa)H=aH \rbrace$ ?

Comment: @Lewis: you need the appropriate quantifiers. It means the kernel consists of $x$ such that $xaH = aH$ for all $a \in G$. From here, you can show that the kernel is in fact the intersection $\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$ of all conjugates of $H$.