# $G$ simple group and there exists a subgroup of index $n$. Show that: $|G|$ divides $n!/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a simple group and there exists a subgroup $H$ of index $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 3}$. Show that: $|G|$ divides $n!/2.$ I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88719/how-to-prove-that-if-g-is-a-group-with-a-subgroup-h-of-index-n-then-g-h).

There was written:
"The proof is really simple. Let $X$ be the set of left cosets of $H$. Consider $\phi: G \to \text{Sym}(X)$ given by $\phi(x)(aH)=(xa)H$. Then $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Consider now $K=\ker \phi$. Then $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Finally, $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Sym}(X)$, which has order $n!$, where $n=[G:H]$. Thus, $[G:K]$ is finite and divides $n!$."

In fact, I don't understand the last sentence. "Thus, $[G:K]$ is finite and divides $n!$." Also did I understand it right that $ker(\phi)=H$? 
Can you also give me an advice how to proof it for $n \ge 3$. (maybe induction)

Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sym(X), is the group of permutations of the collections of cosets, $G/H$. As $H$ has index $n$, this group Sym($X$) is of order $n!$. As $K$ is the kernal of $\phi$  we see$\phi$ leads to an injective homomorphism  $G/K\to Sym(X)$ and by Lagrange's theorem its order should divide $n!$. As there is anormal subgroup of index 2 (consisting of even permutations) in Sym($X$), the image of the simple group $G$ should be contained in that normal subgroup otherwise its intersection will lead to a proper normal subgroup in $G$, contradicting its simplicity.  So $|G|$ divides $n!/2$

EDIT: I should explore if it is possible for image of $\phi$ to have trivial intersection with Alt(X). In that case the sign homomorphism $S_n\to\{\pm1\}$ *restricts* to  a non-trivial homomorphism on Image of $G$, whose kernel  gives a proper nontrivial normal subgroup in image of $G$ and hence on $G$ contradicting the simplicity of $G$.

Comment: Why there is a subgroup of index 2?

Comment: Alt(X) is a subgroup of index 2 in Sym(X), that is of order $n!/2$.

Comment: But $S_X$ isn't the image of $G$.

Comment: Doesn't have to be. The image is a subgroup of Alt(X).

Comment: First of all you use explicitly say that "$S_x$, the image of the simple group $G$". Second of all you should explain why the image of $G$ is a subgroup of $A_X$, which is true, but not obvious.

Comment: Read the last but one statement in my answer.

Comment: In my opinion you still haven't discarded the possibility of a trivial intersection, i.e. $\phi[G] \cap A_5 = \{e\}$, which is possible, as the fact that $G$ is simple isn't violated.

Comment: I'll edit the answer now to rule out this possibility.

Comment: sry can you explain the last step to me once more, I try to understand it but it doesn't work ...

Comment: @milui If $\sigma: S \to \{\pm 1\}$, then if the intersection of $\phi[G]$ and $A_5$ is trivial then we must have both odd and even permutations in $\phi[G]$, so then $\phi \sigma$ is a surjective homomorphism and the kernel of $\phi \sigma$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$, which is impossible.

BTW Vanchinathan, now it looks better.