# If $G$ is simple and finite, and H subgroup then $|G|$ divides $[G:H]!/2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, simple-groups

I'm having trouble to prove that if $G$ is a finite simple group and $H$ is a subgroup of finite index, then $|G|$ divides $\frac{k!}{2}$, where $k$ is the index of H.

I've prove that in this conditions $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $F$ of the symmetric group of $k$, $S_k$. As we are trying to prove that $|G| = |F|$ divides $\frac{k!}{2}$ I think that I need to show that $F \leq A_k$ where $A_k$ is the alternating group, but I don't get to see clearly why this is true.

Also, I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994260/g-simple-group-and-there-exists-a-subgroup-of-index-n-show-that-g-divi) but don't completely understand the answer. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assume $H\neq G$, of course... Also, the statement is false for $G=C_2$ and $H=\{e\}$. Then $k=2$, but $|G|$ does not divide $\frac{2!}{2}=1$. So assume $G\neq C_2$.

Let $G$ act on the cosets of $H$, which gives us a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to S_k$; the kernel is normal in $G$, but cannot equal $G$ because $H\neq G$ and the action is transitive. Hence, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_k$.

Now, $\varphi(G)\cap A_k$ is normal in $\varphi(G)$, since $A_k$ is normal in $S_k$. Thus, either $\varphi(G)\cap A_k=\varphi(G)$, or else $\varphi(G)\cap A_k=\{e\}$.

In the latter case, let $g\in G$, $g\neq e$. Then $\varphi(g^2)=e$, since $\varphi(g)^2\in A_k\cap \varphi(G)$. Thus, $\varphi(G)$ has exponent $2$ and is abelian, hence being simple you must have $G$ cyclic of order $2$, contradicting our working assumption that $G\neq C_2$. Thus, $\varphi(G)\cap A_k$ cannot be trivial, and so $\varphi(G)\cap A_k=\varphi(G)$, proving that $\varphi(G)\subseteq A_k$. Thus, $|G|=|\varphi(G)|$ divides $|A_k| = \frac{k!}{2}$, as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Assume $|G|\gt2$ and $k\gt1$.  Let $G$ act by left multiplication on the set of cosets $G/H$.  Then we get a morphism $\varphi:G\to S_k$.  Furthermore, $\varphi(G)\cong G$, since the kernel has to be trivial.  Now $A_k\cap\varphi(G)$ is normal in $\varphi(G)$.  From there it takes a little more work to get that $\varphi(G)\leqslant A_k$.

Comment: You're right @Arturo.  I don't know that.